# Interceptor with spring3 - context inititialization failed

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am trying to run some simple interceptor on `controller` behind `/index` url. Usisng this piece of docs http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor. Here is my bean:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /index
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myinter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myinter" class="my.classes.myinterceptor">
</bean>
```

but unfortunattelly I got:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'handlerMapping' defined in ServletContext
resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
bean named '' is defined
```

Thanks in advice.

edit, here is my interceptor:

```
package my.classes;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class myinterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletResponse response){
        try {
                    System.out.println("bla bla");
            response.sendRedirect("http://google.com");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please clean and build and then try to deploy the same.

Comment: Thx for advice but `mvn clean install` didn't help unfortunatelly

Comment: may be you can take xml content in some plain text editor and look for the wierd character or some new line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.3/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html) is to map a url to some handler bean. You are failing to define that handler bean. Try mapping the url to some controller in your context by bean id like below.

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /index=someController
        </value>
    </property>...
```

Comment: Thanks now it seems work, but I don't know how to get sure if really there is running interceptor class? `system.out.println("bla bla");` doesn't work...

Comment: Would need more information about your project to help you there.

Comment: Check my interceptor code now. It seems it doesn't work - browser doesn't redirect me to google....

Comment: Is it running your controller as expected?